# Cannot do S3 PutObject from EC2 instance created in ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I receive the following error when attempting to do a PutObject in my S3 bucket from an EC2 instance created in ELB:

> AccessDenied: Access Denied status code: 403, request id:
>   REDACTED, host id:
>   REDACTED

They're in the same VPC. I added the following bucket policy to resolve the error, but no luck:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1397632521961",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1552298259912",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::REDACTED/*",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpc": "REDACTED"
                }
            },
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1397632521960",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1552298259911",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::REDACTED/*",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1:REDACTED:environment/REDACTED/REDACTED"
                }
            },
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, EC2 instances are not created by ELB (Elastic Load Balancer), I think you are referring to Elastic Beanstalk instead (I know, sometime names are confusing)

I assume the IAM policy you posted is correctly attached to your EC2 instances.  Please check this in the EC2 console.

If it is, I would suggest to remove the condition part.  This is not necessary when policies are attached to the EC2 instance.  See the example policies in the doc : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-instanceprofile.html

Policy to attach to your EC2 instance:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1397632521960",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1552298259911",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::REDACTED/*"
        }
    ]
}
```